# Why is it that the return statement in my method doesn't want to return a string?

Tags: java, string, return

I'm new to java so please, bear with me. 
I have this method where the return-statement does not work, because it can't change the object into a string. I've tried several things I found on the internet with no results.

```
private BSTNode find(String courseCode) {
        BSTNode current = root;

        if(current.getCourseCode().compareTo(courseCode)<0){
            current = current.left;
        }else if (current.getCourseCode().compareTo(courseCode)>0){
            current = current.right;
        }

        //return new BSTNode(current.getCourseCode(), current.getCourseName(), current.getCredits());  //Mottagaren av anropet kan inte konvertera till sträng. Varför?
        return current.getCourseName().toString();
    }
```

Anyone seeing what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `BSTNode` a `String`? Probably not

Comment: Look at the very first line: the method `find()` is supposed to return a `BSTNode`, not a `String`.

Comment: Your method's declared return type is `BSTNode`. That means it must return a `BSTNode`, not a `String`. If you want to return a string, your method needs an appropriate return type.

Comment: No it isn't, but why can't I use .toString() to make it that way?

Comment: I know that, but why can't I change it into a string?

Comment: @AnnieFrannie you can return a `String`, but then you would have to change the method signature to: `private` **`String`** `find(String courseCode)`.

Comment: @AnnieFrannie As you have clearly mentioned return type as `BSTNode`. You can either return `BSTNode` or `null`.

Comment: Java is a statically typed language, which means that a `String` can not be a `BSTNode` without your own conversion logic.

Comment: @lealceldeiro what do you mean (isn't that exactly the method signature I already have?)

Comment: @Vikalp Patel  ok, but if it has to return a BSTNode-object then how to change it to a string in the main method? (I didn't get that to work either)

Comment: @AnnieFrannie nope, you have `private` **`BSTNode`** `find(String courseCode)`. I said you would need to change it to `private` **`String`** `find(String courseCode)`

Answer (score 2):

You function should return a BSTNode and not a string. If you want to return a String change the 
`private BSTNode find(String courseCode)` to `private String find(String courseCode)`. Otherwise you should just return `current`.

You can't just change the return type of a function by calling .toString on the object. The return type is defined by the method declaration and not by what you actually return.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning a type `BSTNode` but you are trying to return a string.

Replace the first line, `private BSTNode find(String courseCode) {` with `private String find(String courseCode) {`